# Virtual not working in other system wamp

Tags: php, http, wamp

Virtual host not working in the NETWORK

I just followed this site tutorial, 
[Virtual host steps](http://cesaric.com/?p=255)
The tutorial was excellent but when I try this alias URL in another system, its not working.  I have checked in my other system, I am able to see my application, after I did these changes I am not able to see my application on the other system.

I have even changed Allow from 127.0.0 to all but that is not working.

My C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2.11\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf
This what I added

```
      <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@developertalk
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/developertalk"
    ServerName developertalk
    ServerAlias www.developertalk
    ErrorLog "logs/developertalk-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/developertalk-access.log" common
    <directory "C:/wamp/www/developertalk">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride all
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from all
    </directory>        
</VirtualHost>
```

When hitting URL in another system, getting following error:

```
Server not found
```

In my local host i am having 3 web application.

Due to above changes my local host other sites not working.

How to make it work other sites.

Comment: What you mean by "not working"? Permission denied or which error?Can you post you vhost config also?

Comment: Did you update the hosts file on the other system to point to the IP address of the machine running the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use local DNS to say every PC in Your network, that You have on Your PC host 'myApp', also You can add to every client's hosts file something like `myapp    192.168.1.2` where 192.168.1.2 Your static IP in network

Comment: in which place, or which file i should do this

Comment: on Win `c:/Windows/system32/drivers/etc/hosts` (or something like that), on Linux `/etc/hosts`

Comment: 127.0.0.1       localhost
192.168.3.106       eproknowledgedesk

Comment: now You can go to any PC in your network, open hosts file on it and add line `192.168.3.106 eproknowledgedesk` :)

Comment: in other PC, wamp not installed

Comment: yeah, but on another PC you'll write **Your** IP (`192.168.3.106`), where wamp installed ;)

Comment: i have only 6 reputation, in network, in my network, wamp installed in my system only, i dont want to install that WAMP in all system. is there a way ?

Comment: Ok, Let's try this way: step 1) Install WAMP on Your PC(IP:`192.168.3.106`), configure vhosts and hosts(`192.168.3.106 myhost`), that allow You to get Your webserver through http://myhost/ step 2) Now Your PC is a real web-server, all You need is say another PCs that. Go to every PC You want to use Your web-server and configure their hosts like yours. Now they know where to find `myhost` (`192.168.3.106` as wrote in hosts). step 3) That's all.

Answer (score 0):

For every computer you want to have access to http://developertalk, you need to edit the Hosts file in each one.
Located at (xp/win7): C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\

You need to add only 1 line on every computer.

```
(your static internal ip) www.developertalk
```

example:

```
192.168.1.71 www.developertalk
```

you can check your internal ip address on your windows by opening cmd and typing ipconfig.
Look for the IPv4 address under the Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection column.

If you don't request or assign a static internal IP to your computer, others will not be able to connect to http://developertalk which was forwarded to your old internal IP.

Egor Sazanovich has actually answered your question and provided you with extra information, so accept his instead of this one, if this helped at all.